# RuntimeException laravel 5.8 RuntimeException This driver does not support creating temporary URLs

Tags: laravel-5.8

> RuntimeException This driver does not support creating temporary URLs.

I am trying to generating **Temp Url** for every request **Laravel version 5.8** below code trying showing an error.

This driver does not support creating temporary URLs.

```
$url = "66.jpeg";
$url = Storage::disk('public')->url($url);
$url = Storage::disk('public')->temporaryUrl(
        '66.jpeg', now()->addMinutes(5)
);
```

Answer (score 2):

From my knowledge, `temporaryUrl` is a method used on a drivers such as `s3` to create a temporary url for a privately stored asset.

If you would like to set a temporary url for a file, it may help to use `Cache` to temporarily store the path.

`Cache` can set a `key/value` for a **set amount of time**. A url can be create which links to an endpoint. Then endpoint can then be created which returns the contents of that file:

```
// Creating temp file index in cache

$image = '66.jpg';

Cache::put('/temp/' . $image, 300); // 5 minutes
```

Now in, for example, `TempController.php` (visiting `http://example.com/temp/66.jpg`):

```
public function show($image)
{
    if (Cache::get('/temp/' . $image) && ! Storage::disk('public')->exists($image)) {
        // not in cache or do not exist, maybe redirect...
    };

    return Storage::disk('public')->get($image);
}
```

This is a proof of concept however I hope this helps.